# IBM Watson text-to-speech in Python: No such child resource

Tags: python, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I am trying to generate an audio file based on a simple text:

```
from ibm_watson import TextToSpeechV1
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('O6...............N')
text_to_speech = TextToSpeechV1(authenticator=authenticator)

text_to_speech.set_service_url('https://api.eu-gb.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/b95d7....................956/v1/synthesize')
```

However, I get the following output:

```
ERROR:root: No such child resource.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/anaconda2/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/base_service.py", line 229, in send
    response.status_code, error_message, http_response=response)
ibm_cloud_sdk_core.api_exception.ApiException: Error: No such child resource., Code: 404 , X-global-transaction-id: 834e9.................698f5
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

for `set_service_url`, use the base url `https://api.eu-gb.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com`, as shown in the [API reference](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech?code=python#service-endpoint).

Then you can call the `synthesize` method (see the [example](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech?code=python#synthesize-audio) in the API reference).

```
with open('hello_world.wav', 'wb') as audio_file:
    audio_file.write(
        text_to_speech.synthesize(
            'Hello world',
            voice='en-US_AllisonVoice',
            accept='audio/wav'        
        ).get_result().content)
```